# List of answers thmtools

Tags: thmtools, endfloat

I've created such file for sheets with exercises.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont={\normalsize\bfseries},
  spaceabove=10pt,
  spacebelow=10pt
]{exstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=exstyle, title={Exercise}, numberwithin=section]{myexercise}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont={\normalsize\bfseries},
  spaceabove=10pt,
  spacebelow=10pt
]{ansstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=ansstyle, title={}, numberwithin=section]{myanswer}



\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\blindtext

\begin{myexercise}
  This is the first exercise.
\end{myexercise}
\begin{myanswer}
  The answer to the first exercise. It's shown here but it shouldn't be! Pls look at the end of the page.
\end{myanswer}

\begin{myexercise}
  This is the second exercise.
\end{myexercise}
\begin{myanswer}
  The answer to the second exercise. It's shown here but it shouldn't be! Pls look at the end of the page.
\end{myanswer}

\blindtext

Here (at the end of the section) I want to have a command smth like showallanswers, which will print the list:

\textbf{Answers for exercise in first section:}

1.1 The answer to the first exercise.

1.2 The answer to the second exercise.

Exercises in the second section will have numeration from 1.1 again.

\end{document}
```

MWE does this:

[image]

How to create a command which places the list of answers at the end of each section?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `endfloat` and declare the environment `myanswer` as a delayed float. Then simply call `\processdelayedfloats` before each next section. You can even redefine the a `\mysection` command that would do that automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont={\normalsize\bfseries},
  spaceabove=10pt,
  spacebelow=10pt
]{exstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=exstyle, title={Exercise}, numberwithin=section]{myexercise}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont={\normalsize\bfseries},
  spaceabove=10pt,
  spacebelow=10pt
]{ansstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=ansstyle, title={}, numberwithin=section]{myanswer}

\DeclareDelayedFloat{myanswer}{Answer}
\SetupDelayedFloat{myanswer}{nolist}

% Allow multiple float on the same page
\renewcommand\efloatseparator{\mbox{}}
% No break page before the floats.
\renewcommand\efloatbegin{}

\newcommand{\shallowanswer}{
\paragraph{Answers for exercise in first section:}
\processdelayedfloats
}
\begin{document}


\section{First section}

\blindtext

\begin{myexercise}
  This is the first exercise.
\end{myexercise}
\begin{myanswer}
  The answer to the first exercise. It's shown here but it shouldn't be! Pls look at the end of the page.
\end{myanswer}

\begin{myexercise}
  This is the second exercise.
\end{myexercise}
\begin{myanswer}
  The answer to the second exercise. It's shown here but it shouldn't be! Pls look at the end of the page.
\end{myanswer}

\blindtext

\shallowanswer
\end{document}
```

[image]